# Payment method nonce or token

Tags: node.js, braintree, nonce

When I use Braintree, I have to generate a payment nonce from the client token and the information about the card (number, expiration, ...).
Once it is generated, I can process the payment by `BraintreeGateway.transaction.sale`[sale](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/node)
How is the expiration of the payment nonce?
Can I use it several times, even a month later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The nonce will expire after 3 hours.**

References:

- Braintree Documentation: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview#payment-method-nonce
- Used it myself, and had a similar query